# classroom how to add a document url to an existing material, in an existing topic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I usually have about 70 classroom opened per month.
All my classrooms have the same structure in Course Work section, sometimes I need to use scripts to add a pdf url or a mp3/mp4 url to a specific Material, that is inside a specific Topic.

Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create doesn't work in this case, because inserts the document in the existing topic, but creates a new material. It can't insert in an existing material, at least I haven't been able to figure out if it can do it.

Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.patch modifies only some of the fields of the material, but can't add a link.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the current stage, it seems that `materials` is not included in `updateMask` of "Method: courses.courseWorkMaterials.patch". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials/patch) By this, I'm worried that your goal might not be able to be directly achieved. For example, as a workaround, how about adding the materials by copying the existing course work material? But, if that was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: Yes I should delete the existing material and add another one with the new document included, but that would alter the sequence. Anyway, I will made some changes in my internal procedures to override this. Thx a lot for your answer.